# Java array printing asterisk

Tags: java, arrays

I know this is just a simple java array problem, but I don't have any idea how to do this.What I want to do is like this:

Student    Score    Graph
John                3    ********* 
Mark                2    **
James              1    *

What I have in mind is an array like this:

```
String[][] students = { { "John", "Mark", "James" }, { "3", "2", "1" } };
```

How will I print the line graph without adding another set of variables in the array? I want it to just display asterisks (*) according to the number of score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
    String[][] students = { { "John", "Mark", "James" }, { "3", "2", "1" } };
    for (int i = 0; i < students[0].length; i++) {
        StringBuilder asterix = new StringBuilder();
        for (int acnt = 0; acnt < Integer.parseInt(students[1][i]); acnt++)
            asterix.append("*");
        System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s", students[0][i], students[1][i],asterix.toString());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output

```
John    3   ***
Mark    2   **
James   1   *
```

Comment: Hi tried your code, but it just gives me 3 johns, 2 marks and 1 james?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes Just copy paste it and try. It works as per your question. *** for John, ** for Mark and * for James

Comment: oh because I closed the inner loop below System.out.println();

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
int gradeAsInt = Integer.parseInt (students [1][n]);
for (int i = 0; i < gradeAsInt; ++i) System.out.print ("*");
```

Comment: Note that [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) can be used to convert the string into a number that can be used in a for loop.

Comment: It's an index into the array object.

Comment: So should it start with 0? What I did is: int n = 0;

Comment: @RohitJain `N` should be as 1

Comment: It should be `students [1][n]` First row 0...n Columns.

Comment: @RohitJain agreed with AmitD:) i think so the values are [1][0][1][1][1][2] should be printed as *